# Reducing damage from acid burns

Tags: acid-base

Pretty simple: If you do not have access to water, what could reduce damage from getting acid on your skin?

I'm a total noob - I studied philosophy - but I know bases neutralize acids. I have a vague sort of idea coal does too? Are there other ways?

Comment: Coal does not. Bases do, but they can inflict even more severe damage by themselves. The other ways are worse yet. In short, if you do not have access to _a lot of_ water, don't mess with acids and chemistry in general.

Comment: I'm not messing with anything. I'm thinking that from time to time - 700+ times a year in London for instance - you might be happily strolling about the park, when someone suddenly applies acid to your face.

I was thinking of options for emergency treatment, so that victims might wake up the next day with less scarring.

Comment: Wow, so that's a real problem. Well, then a bottle of water or a public drinking fountain is your best bet. Other ways are less reliable **and** less available.

Comment: That's a pretty real problem. I imagined maybe some sort of wet wipe, something cheap and disposable you could keep in a pocket or purse. An acid attack first aid kit. 

As you can see, I don't know a lot about chemistry. But then that's why I ask someone wiser =)